# Creating a function to summarise the paired "Factors" which are currently stored in 2 columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have a large (>200000 observations) flat file dataframe which has multiple "paired" codes throughout it. For each pair, one column contains a numerical code, the second is a description of the code. I have set both the codes and descriptions to "factors".

An example of the dataframe is below

```
|-------------|---------------|---------------|-------------|---------------|---------  
|      ID     |   Unit_CD     |      Unit     |    Name_CD  |      Name     |     etc  
|-------------|---------------|---------------|-------------|---------------|---------  
|      01     |       12      |      Bob      |      A01    |      EPID     |     etc
|      02     |       10      |      Sue      |      A04    |      UPIM     |     etc
|      03     |       12      |      Bob      |      V03    |      AVRM     |     etc
|      04     |       14      |      Moo      |      A04    |      UPIM     |     etc
```

I would like to create a function where you can input the 2 paired column names and it will return a concatenated field which displays the numeric code and the description as per below:

'code.names(df,Unit_CD,Unit)'

OUTPUT:
Unit Codes
10: Sue
12: Bob
14: Moo

I have written the following code however I can not get it to accept the column names as an input to the function:

```
code.names <- function(df,column1, column2){

    n <-count(df,column1,column2)
    CD.V <- as.vector(n[,1])
    CD.Code <- as.vector(n[,2])
    
    
    i <- nrows(n)
    for (i in 1:n){ 
      paste(CD.V[i],CD.Code[i])
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is

```
 Error: Must group by variables found in `.data`.
* Column `column1` is not found.
* Column `column2` is not found.
```

As I am doing this multiple times through the code, I would prefer to set this up as a function, however any other method of achieving my end goal would still be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest this approach with a new function using your data and the names of the columns to be concatenated:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, Unit_CD = c(12L, 10L, 12L, 14L), Unit = c("Bob", 
"Sue", "Bob", "Moo"), Name_CD = c("A01", "A04", "V03", "A04"), 
    Name = c("EPID", "UPIM", "AVRM", "UPIM")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Code:

```
#Function
myfun <- function(x,cola,colb)
{
  var <- paste0(x[,cola],': ',x[,colb])
  var <- unique(var)
  var <- data.frame(var)
  return(var)
}
#Apply
myfun(df,'Unit_CD', 'Unit')
```

Output:

```
      var
1 12: Bob
2 10: Sue
3 14: Moo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `duplicated` to keep only unique values in the dataframe.

```
code.names <- function(df,column1, column2) {
  df1 <- df[!duplicated(df[c(column1, column2)]), ]
  cat(paste(df1[[column1]], df1[[column2]], sep = ":", collapse = "\n"))
}

code.names(df, 'Unit_CD','Unit')

#12:Bob
#10:Sue
#14:Moo
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope the code below works for your goal

```
code.names <- function(df,column1, column2) unique(paste0(df[[column1]],":",df[[column2]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `unite`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    distinct(Unit_CD, Unit) %>%
    unite(New, Unit_CD, Unit, sep=": ")
#      New
#1 12: Bob
#2 10: Sue
#3 14: Moo
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, Unit_CD = c(12L, 10L, 12L, 14L), Unit = c("Bob", 
"Sue", "Bob", "Moo"), Name_CD = c("A01", "A04", "V03", "A04"), 
    Name = c("EPID", "UPIM", "AVRM", "UPIM")), class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```